# Determining if the window is in help mode

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Developing a .NET WinForms application: how can I check if the window is in Help mode (i.e. after clicking the "?" button in the title bar)?

The problem I have is that my System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem objects do not have a HelpRequested event (because they do not inherit from Control) so in the Click event handler, I am trying to determine if the window is currently in help mode so I can popup a ToolTip programmatically.

Any help is always appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the [Form.HelpButtonClicked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.helpbuttonclicked.aspx) event is what you want, since it's in your namespace.

Comment: That event tells you when the help button is pressed and "help mode" starts, but how do you know when help mode ends?  Since it is possible to click on an empty part of the form that doesn't fire the HelpRequested event but stops help mode, you can't assume HelpRequested will always be called when help mode stops.